# Querying data when only some are valid

Tags: python, pandas, exception, quandl

I've been playing around with Quandl databases, and I wanted to write a piece of code that goes through all their free stock price charts and puts it into a Pandas Database. I created a ticker that has every stock on the NYSE, but Quandl only gives free access to a few stocks, so my query involves alot of invalid data, which causes an exception. What I'm trying to do is handle the exception in a way that if a stock is available on Quandl it will go in the database, and if not the code simply passes over it without doing anything. Here's my code so far:

```
    countries = pd.read_html('http://www.nationsonline.org/oneworld/country_code_list.htm')
real_countries = countries[2]
for abbv in real_countries[3]:
    query = 'UNAE/GVAKD_'+str(abbv)
```

What should the try and except statements look like?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are some immediate problems here.

```
real_countries = countries[2]
```

returns a single value from the list. For example,

```
countries = ['spain', 'france', 'uk']
real_countries = countries[2]
real_countries
```

returns

```
'uk'
```

since it is the 0 1 2 position in the list. So then calling

```
real_countries[3]
```

returns

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-32ebd2273102> in <module>()
----> 1 real_countries[3]

IndexError: string index out of range
```

So it's hard to understand what you're going for here.

What I think you want is: if value in list then string+value as new_list

so we can approach that kind of like:

```
string_to_add = 'UNAE/GVAKD_'
query_list = [value+string_to_add if value in real_countries else None for value in countries]
```

So now at least you have your query list, and then you can loop over that again to actually do your queries. But you still need to determine your "real countries" by not slicing out a single value, which you did via countries[2].

Comment: sorry I wasn't clear, countries is a list of dataframes, since that's what is returned by read_html. real_countries then picks out the dataframe I want from that list.

Comment: I don't understand. Are you just trying to add the 'UNAE/GVAKD_' string to each country in your "real_countries" dataFrame?

Comment: Yes, and then use that list as a query through quandl's database. Btw, I just realized that these aren't countries, that name was left over from a different code. These are stocks. what I've done is create a list of all stocks on the NYSE, and I want to use that to query through quandl stock price databases. The issue is, they don't have a database for every single stock, only a few, so some of my queried symbols show up as an error.

Comment: This entire process is going to be a lot more productive if you edit your original question with this information you've shared here in the comments and post some example data and what you want your output to finally look like.